# NAudio.dll signing with a strong key fails

Tags: c#, .net, code-signing, naudio

Is there any copy of `NAudio.dll` and `NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat.dll` that is pre-signed with a .pfx key already? I can't seem to sign it myself. When I try to recompile the source code to get the .dlls signed: I get the following error: [image: Error when attempting to compile NAudio]

Is there a way around this, or a way to have it compile properly?

I'd prefer to avoid this whole process and just have the .dll pre-signed to avoid Anti-Viruses freaking out over it.

Comment: You can't recompile it, because the Test Project needs to be signed, too. Sign NAudioTests, too. It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, using `InternalsVisibleTo` from a signed assembly requires the assembly it's trusting to be signed too.

You need to sign both the test project *and* the production project... or (if you really must) ditch the tests, and remove the `InternalsVisibleTo(NAudioTests)`.

If you want the prepackaged versions of the assemblies to be signed, I suggest you file a feature request on the project site.